# Framework for posterior inference in discrete time series models

Tags: python, framework

I am looking at a research problem where I have a discrete time series model as follows:

```
X[0] = a; Y[0] = b; X[t], Y[t] > 0 for all t=0 to n.

X[t+1] = X[t] - B[t]
Y[t+1] = Y[t] + B[t] - C[t]

B[t] ~ Binom(X[t], 1-exp(-alpha/Y[t])); alpha > 0
C[t] ~ Binom(Y[t], 1-exp(-beta)); beta > 0
Likelihood L(B, C|params) = product of p(B[t]|params)*p(C[t]|params) for t=0 to n.
```

Only `C[t]` is observed, and `a` and `b` are known. I am interested in the posterior distribution of the parameters `alpha` and `beta`. A point estimate is also fine. In particular, I am looking for:

1. a framework to make MCMC estimation of the posterior.
2. or, a framework for computing expectation maximization on marginal likelihood `L(C|params)`.

So far I have tried to implement the whole model from scratch in numpy. The resulting code is inefficient, error-prone, and I need to make major changes in the code every time I make changes in model parameterization.

I have also searched for frameworks and found Stan. It seems to be doing what I want. However, I have two concerns.

1. It does not seem to support discrete latent time series variables.
2. In my MCMC, I have noticed that a simple proposal distribution centered at the previous value has very slow mixing for `B[t]`. So, I would like to pass in a custom proposal distribution (in this case `Binom(S[t], .))` that improves mixing. I found no way to do so in Stan.

Therefore, what framework (preferably in python) would you suggest for this task? Also, please let me know if this is not the right question for this forum.

Comment: Welcome zigs!  This Stack Exchange site definitely accepts questions like yours! :)